# iOS custom cell expandable - index 0 issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, custom-cell

Thanks for the help.
I have a custom cell that I expand using the following code. However, the first cell (index 0) always expands upon launch of the ViewControllers?

What am I missing? How do you have them all unExpanded upon launch and expand only upon selection.

Many Thanks.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        CustomCellCell *cell;
        static NSString *cellID=@"myCustomCell";
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

        if (cell == nil) 
        {
            NSArray *test = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"myCustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];
            if([test count]>0)
            {
                for(id someObject in test)
                { 
                    if ([someObject isKindOfClass:[CustomCellCell class]]) {
                        cell=someObject;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        cell.LableCell.text = [testArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        NSLog( @"data testarray table %@", [testArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]);
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        return cell;
    }

    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        self.selectedRow = indexPath.row;
        CustomCellCell *cell = (CustomCellCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView endUpdates];

        cell.buttonCell.hidden = NO;
        cell.textLabel.hidden = NO;
        cell.textfiledCell.hidden = NO;
        cell.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        cell.clipsToBounds = YES;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        if(selectedRow == indexPath.row) {
            return 175;
        }

        return 44;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because default value of `selectedRow` is zero. You need to initialize it as,

```
selectedRow = NSIntegerMax; //or selectedRow = -1;
```

or some other default value. You can add this in `viewDidLoad` method or so. Whenever you declare an int type variable, it is default value is zero. So if you have a scenario where zero needs to be checked for example in the above case, you should default it to a value which wont be used at all. Either a negative value or `NSIntegerMax` can be used for this.

Comment: @AhabLives, not a problem. Normally people tend to miss that. Please accept if this helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that selectedRow is an integer instance variable. That integer begins life with a value of 0. As the first table cell is row 0, it matches selectedRow even though you have not intentionally set it.

One way to solve this would be to store selectedRow as an NSIndexPath instead of an integer.

Then you could just do this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if([selectedRow isEqual:indexPath]) {
        return 175;
    }
    return 44;
}
```

And because selectedRow will default to nil, you won't get a false match. It is also more flexible if you decide to use sections later on.